# SQL query in Java does not work, no error is appearing but the data isn't appearung in DB

Tags: java, database

I try to insert a row to the database, but it doesn't appear in the table after running:

This is the main class:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CouponsDbDao coupDbDao = new CouponsDbDao();
        Coupon coupon = new Coupon(1, 0, Category.Food, null, null, null, null, 25, 0, null);
        coupDbDao.addCoupon(coupon);
    }
}
```

And this is the method:

```
public class CouponsDbDao {
    public void addCoupon(Coupon coupon) {
        try {
        Connection connection = JdbcUtils.getConnection();
        String sqlStatement = "insert into coupons (COMPANY_ID,CATEGORY_ID,TITLE,DESCRIPTION,START_DATE,END_DATE,AMOUNT,PRICE,IMAGE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);

            statement.setInt(1, coupon.getCompanyId());
            statement.setObject(2, coupon.getCategory());
            statement.setString(3, coupon.getTitle());
            statement.setString(4, coupon.getDescription());
            statement.setDate(5, coupon.getStartDate());
            statement.setDate(6, coupon.getEndDate());
            statement.setInt(7, coupon.getAmount());
            statement.setDouble(8, coupon.getPrice());
            statement.setString(9, coupon.getImage());
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never call `statement.executeUpdate()`

Comment: I suggest you treat `Connection` in try-with-resources

Comment: thank you! its working now

Answer (score 1):

You need to **execute** the statement after setting values. Additionally, you need to close the connection created, the preparedstatement etc in a **finally** block.

```
public class CouponsDbDao {
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
public void addCoupon(Coupon coupon) {
    try {
       connection= JdbcUtils.getConnection();
       String sqlStatement = "insert into coupons (COMPANY_ID,CATEGORY_ID,TITLE,DESCRIPTION,START_DATE,END_DATE,AMOUNT,PRICE,IMAGE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
       statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);

        statement.setInt(1, coupon.getCompanyId());
        statement.setObject(2, coupon.getCategory());
        statement.setString(3, coupon.getTitle());
        statement.setString(4, coupon.getDescription());
        statement.setDate(5, coupon.getStartDate());
        statement.setDate(6, coupon.getEndDate());
        statement.setInt(7, coupon.getAmount());
        statement.setDouble(8, coupon.getPrice());
        statement.setString(9, coupon.getImage());

        statement.executeUpdate();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
       if (statement != null) {
          try {
              statement.close();
          } catch (SQLException e) { /* print here */}
        }
        if (connection != null) {
          try {
              connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) { /* print here */}
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better (and easier) to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead of using such convoluted finally blocks.

Comment: How do you know he's using "legacy code"? Besides, nothing in the question indicates this, and try-with-resources works in Java 7 and higher and requires nothing extra other than compiling and running on Java 7 or higher.

Comment: It's an assumption. Since he's not using try-with-resources. The finally block ensures he doesn't have to change java versions. Maybe he can't upgrade. It might be old enterprise code. In any case, he's already solved it. So, we need to move on.

Comment: It is far more likely they are not aware of try-with-resources than that they are still using Java 6 or older.

Comment: Yes, other users have already explained to him about try-with-resources.

Answer (score 1):

As told by others you need to call [`executeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) to really perform the query:

> **Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object**, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE

I suggest you also to use the [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

This has been introduced in java 7 and let you eliminate the finally boiler plate code as follow:

```
// ORIGINAL CODE
Connection connection = ...
try {
   connection = JdbcUtils.getConnection();
   ... 
   statement.executeUpdate();
    
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   if (statement != null) {
      try {
          statement.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) { /* print here */}
    }
    if (connection != null) {
      try {
          connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) { /* print here */}
  }
}
```

becomes:

```
// USING try with resources
try (Connection connection = JdbcUtils.getConnection()) {
   ... 
   statement.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}  // NO need of the finally block because connection is AutoCloseable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **execute update** for statement, like:

```
statement.executeUpdate();
```